# Prove this inequality by induction

Tags: induction

I am having trouble proving the following by induction, in particular implementing the IH

$$2^n  > 3n^2 +3n +1~\forall n\in \mathbb{N},n\geq8$$

Answer (score 2):

First prove $$3n^2>3n+6 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for} \thinspace n \geq 3 \hspace{1cm} (1),$$ by induction .

Suppose $$ 3n^2>3n+6,$$
then
$$ 3(n+1)^2=3n^2+6n+3>3n+6+6n+3=9n+9>3n+9=3(n+1)+6.$$

Now we prove $2^n > 3n^2+3n+1$ for all $n \geq 8$. Base case $n=8$ is just evaluating.

Now,
induction hypothesis:
$$ 2^n > 3n^2+3n+1.$$
Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
2^{n+1}=2 \cdot 2^n >2(3n^2+3n+1)&=6n^2+6n+2 \\
&=3n^2+3n^2+6n+2 \\
&> 3n^2 +3n+6+6n+2 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{by} \thinspace (1)\\
&= 3n^2+9n+8 \\
&= 3(n+1)^2+3(n+1)+2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: How exactly is a student, who is asking for helping formulating the inductive hypothesis, supposed to realize he needs to prove (1) ?  Or even accomplish that?  It is rather unkind to respond to a request for help with the first step being an epiphany.

Comment: When one computes $2^{n+1},$ one gets $6n^2+6n+2$ and we need this to be greater than $3n^2+9n+2,$ so what we really need to prove is $6n^2+6n+2>3n^2+9n+8,$ that is, $3n^2>3n+6.$ I just compute this first for the proof to be more orderly but using induction hypothesis leads directly to this.

Answer (score 0):

We prove by induction the following statement is true: $$2^n  > 3n^2 +3n +1~\forall n\in \mathbb{N},n\geq8 \tag{1}$$

We shall re-arrange the statement to fit the following, equivalent form:

$$\frac{2^n}{n^2} > 3\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

When $n = 8$, you can verify the statement is true.

Assume the re-arranged, equivalent, and without loss of generality the same equation is true for $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Is it true for $n+1$?

Substituting yields $\frac{2\cdot2^n}{(n+1)^2} > 3 + \frac{3}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.

Also equivalent:

$$\frac{2^n}{n^2} > 3\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{9}{2n} + \frac{5}{2n^2}\right) \tag{3}$$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(3)$ yields the following fact: $(2)$'s RHS is larger than $(3)$'s RHS for $n \geq 8$, and the difference keeps increasing, i.e. $(3)$'s RHS will always be smaller than $(2)$'s RHS, for $n \geq 8$. Therefore, the statement is true for $n+1$.

Comment: How exactly is a student, who is asking for help formulating the inductive hypothesis, supposed to come up with step 2?

Comment: @DanielV By dividing each side by $n^2$, and factoring the $3$ from the RHS. Not sure what the difficulty is.

Comment: Do you start out all of your inductive arguments by dividing by $n^2$ and factoring out constants?

Comment: @DanielV I do what the situation calls for. Doing such operations in this example allowed me to objectively compare $(1)$ when $n$ was substituted, $(1)$ when $n+1$ was substituted, and ultimately derive a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^n$ grows faster than $3n^2 + 3n + 1$, this is really straightforward.

> in particular implementing the IH

It looks like this:

$$\begin{array} {rll}
2^n &> 2n^2 + 3n + 1 \text{ and } n \ge 8                 & \text{Inductive Hypothesis} \\
&~~\vdots \\
2^{n + 1}&> 2(n + 1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1          & \text{To Establish}
\end{array}$$

Note that your inductive hypothesis is actually 2 assumptions, $2^n > 2n^2 + 3n + 1$ and $n \ge 8$. You have to fill in the $\dots$ with an argument that assumes the hypothesis and leads to the conclusion.  A first simplification would be to multiply both sides of the assumption by 2 :

$$\begin{array} {rll}
2^n &> 2n^2 + 3n + 1 \text{ and } n \ge 8                 & \text{Inductive Hypothesis} \\
2^{n + 1} &> 4n^2 + 6n + 2                      & \text{Multiply both sides by 2} \\
& ~~ \vdots \\
2^{n + 1} &> 2(n + 1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1          & \text{To Establish}
\end{array}$$

Now you assume that $A > B$, and you want to prove $A > C$.  So attempt to establish that $B > C$ (you'll have to use $n \ge 8$).

$$\begin{array} {rll}
n & \ge 8                 & \text{Given} \\
& ~~ \vdots \\
4n^2 + 6n + 2 & > 2(n + 1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1   & \text{To Establish} \\
\end{array}$$

Work backwards, simplifying:

$$\begin{array} {rll}
n & \ge 8                 & \text{Given} \\
& ~~ \vdots \\
2n^2 - n - 4 &> 0                          & \text{To Establish} \\
4n^2 + 6n + 2 &> 2n^2 + 4n + 2 + 3n+3 + 1  & \text{Algebra} \\
4n^2 + 6n + 2 &> 2(n + 1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1   & \text{Algebra} \\
\end{array}$$

Since the coefficient of $n^2$ (the fastest growing term) is positive (2), after a point it will always be positive.  One thing you could do is find the minimum of the quadratic, which occurs at $4n - 1 = 0$ or $n = 1/4$.  Since the polynomial is increasing after $n=1/4$, and is positive at $n = 8$, you can conclude $2n^2 - n - 4 > 0$ which is the last unestablished proposition.

Alternatively, you could establish $\forall n \ge 8 ~:~ 2n^2 - n - 4 > 0$ with induction (I won't show the base case):

$$\begin{array} {rll}
2n^2 - n - 4 &> 0 \text{ and } n \ge 8             & \text{Inductive Hypothesis} \\
& ~~ \vdots \\
2(n + 1)^2 - (n + 1) - 4 & > 0   & \text{To establish} \\
\end{array}$$

Same as before, use algebra etc to finish the proof.

Comment: thank you this really cleared things up

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general hint. 
Suppose we are working to show that $p_d(n) < 2^n$ for all $n \geq N$, where $p_d$ is a degree $d$ polynomial (you have a quadratic in your case).

For our inductive step we assume $p_d(n) < 2^n$ and we then want to show that $p_d(n+1) < 2^{n+1}$ follows.

We can write this as $p_d(n+1) = p_{d}(n) + p_{<d}(n) < 2^n + p_{<d}(n)$,  where $p_{<d}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d-1$ (and we used the inductive hypothesis in our last step) so that our problem is reduced to proving that $p_{<d}(n) < 2^n$ for all $n \geq N$.

This problem is very similar to the one you started with, and once we solve it we've solved the original problem.
We'll do this by induction, checking the base case $n = N$ and then working through the inductive step. So what's happening is we are getting a recursive chain of inductions, which must terminate because each time we dive into the next step, our polynomial has strictly lower degree than before.  Eventually we must get to the problem $C = p_0(n) < 2^n$, which is verifiable immediately (there's no induction to be had).
For your case of comparing a quadratic polynomial to $2^n$, your induction step will give you a linear function to compare with $2^n$, and finally a constant which you'll see is less than $2^8$.

The cool thing about looking at the process abstractly is that it quickly leads to a proof (by induction) that all polynomials exhibit rate of growth lower than exponential.